# jquery prints [object XMLDocument] instead of file content

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click **Show Contact** link below, it should read the file from local disk and print its content. My example below prints ***[object XMLDocument]*** instead of actual content of the file.

Do I have to parse or convert it before printing?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_contact()
    {
        jQuery.get('file:///D:/contact.html', function(data)
        {
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
        });
    }
</script>

<a href="#" title="" onclick="show_contact()">Show Contact</a>
<br />
<p id="content">hi</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the dataType as the third parameter:

```
       jQuery.get('file:///D:/contact.html', function(data)
       {
          document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = data;
       }, 'text');
```